# How to run and compile java project without an IDE and with several packages?

Tags: java

Say I downloaded a project from github and it includes the following files;

- docs > text.pdf (only one file in it, not important)
- src
- README.md

Now let's say the src includes the following files;

- package1

  - class1.java
  - class2.java
  - class3.java
- package2

  - class4.java
- package3

  - class5.java
  - main.java (this is the one that has a main and needs to run but is dependent on everything else)

Now I only have the above, how do I compile and run this only using command line, assuming the project has no errors.

Comment: I would assume you just compile `main.java` using `javac` and run it with `java`

Comment: It's not clear _why_ you want to not use an IDE. Can you use Maven or are you looking to just do it using _javac_ alone?

Comment: so javac src/package3/main.java ?

Comment: just looking to use javac alone

Comment: Use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: and how do I use maven or gradle, is there a link to instructions?

Comment: for maven or gradle you need to write the build instructions.

Comment: Please, at least, go through java docs before asking such questions.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
cd src
javac package3/main.java
java package.main
```

Answer (score 1):

```
javac package1/*.java 
javac package2/*.java
javac package3/*.java

java package3.main
```

First 3 javac will compile and generate class files within those 3 packages.
last line is just run the class files.

Comment: not needed. `javac` has built-in basic `make` capability.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling it all depends on what other tools you have. A make-like tool like ant is helpful for working through dependencies and sets of source files, but then you will still need to be sure that you set up your CLASSPATH to allow the java interpreter/runtime to find all of those class files.

An alternative, and what is often considered the better solution, is to create a jar file with all of the resulting class files and then run the application by executing the jar file. The manifest in the jar file will specify the main class.

I can understand not wanting to install an IDE just to compile an application that you plan to run but not develop, but unless you want to compile each file manually and update your CLASSPATH, I suggest that you use some form of build tool to simplify the process.

Comment: do you mean a makefile type of thing? I've tried to write a makefile but it does not seem to work

Comment: Yes, you need a makefile and the tool make. Ant is popular with Java developers and it works nicely. It understands Java but its configuration files are XML and thus a bit of a pain to edit compared to the plain text of a MAKEFILE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a visual representation of `javac`'s `make`-like capabilities.

[image]

Note that since everything is rooted in the same source tree, all you had to do is `javac p4/Main.java` and it figured out that it needs to compile the classes (e.g. `p1/T.class`) that `Main` needs. It creates `T.class` by compiling `p1/T.java` first.

You also have additional support in the form of `-sourcepath` and `-classpath`. For details see [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: I didnt know it has built-in ...nice